# Is there a way to get all namespace scoped resource objects by label selector using python kubernetes client?

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I want to achieve this command use kubernetes python client.

```bash
kubectl -n namespace get all -l key=value
```

I've seen several questions here [List all resources in a namespace using the Kubernetes python client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787779/list-all-resources-in-a-namespace-using-the-kubernetes-python-client)

but it's means

```bash
kubectl api-resources
```

not what I want.

I can't find an example case, so what is the right way to do this?

Comment: have you checked this [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68196323) and this [solution by addii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74120789/18878095)

Comment: Thank you but neither custom object nor @Aref Riant's suggestion nor dynamic client meets the need. They all need iteration, I'm looking for a way to get resources once.

Answer (score 0):

namespaced resources in Kubernetes api is structured like:

```
/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods
/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/secrets
/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/services
.
.
.
```

just for resources accessible by [Core API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md)

to have access to other resources like StatefulSets, you need to use [Apps API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md)

at the end of the day, you need to name all resources you need to retrieve,

```
from kubernetes import client, config
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
namespace = "default"

pods = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace)
services = v1.list_namespaced_service(namespace)
# And continue for all resources accessible by core api...


appv1 = client.AppsV1Api()
statefulsets = appv1.list_namespaced_stateful_set(namespace)
# And continue for all resources
```

You can use `get_api_resources()` to list all resource names possible, and then iterate over them like the code above, inform in the comments if you needed help.

Comment: Thank you.
Well if this, a dynamic client may be a better choice I think.